# Multi-threaded downloader in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, download-manager

I'm working on a WPF download manager which should support downloading multiple files at the same time through HTTP, adding a new download, pause/resume, displaying and updating each download process information (filename, size, download percentage, time left...) in a DataGrid, displaying progress in a ProgressBar and a bunch of other stuff.

So, the idea is to use a separate thread for each download process, and be able to dynamically create/cancel threads. What is the best way to accomplish this? Using a BackgroundWorker, ThreadPool?

Comment: You may also need multiple threads for each download process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `Thread` directly and keep the references to all the treads that I create.

Answer (score 6):

The [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) XXXAsync methods such as `DownloadFileAsync` already provide you with asynchronous versions of all methods that allow you to perform the HTTP requests on separate threads. They are also *C# 5.0 async* ready.

Since this is a WPF application you should ensure that you are modifying the UI controls only on the main UI thread using the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx) method.

Comment: Yes, well I cannot use WebClient, since it doesn't support pausing/resuming a download, so I have to create a custom wrapper for HttpWebRequest. I think I will have to use a new `Thread` for each process and set it as a background thread.